# setting a mysql root password

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

I just installed mysql-server on Ubuntu 18.0.4.2 LTS and I can now connect to the server just fine when I do `mysql` but I can't connect when I do `mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uroot -p`.

When I logged in just now with `mysql` I did this:

```
SET PASSWORD = 'mypassword';
```

But that got me back this warning:

```
 SET PASSWORD has no significance for user 'root'@'localhost' as authentication plugin does not support it.
```

So how do I set the password for the root user so that I might be able to login with `mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uroot -p` (which I assume is more analogous to what MySQL Workbench would be doing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `MySQL` now trusts the username the client is being run as IF you are connecting via a socket.  You need to change to native password auth, and then set a password.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'mypass';
```